# adding a loading.gif image to .val()

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I add a loading.gif image to .val() in my script?

I have tried:

```
this.submitButton.val('<input type="image" src="http://localhost:8000/loader.gif">').prop('disabled', true);
```

But it doesn't work! Any suggestions ?

Comment: Can you add relevant html and js code? This is very little to work with.

Comment: Well, you certainly can't do it that way, as `element.value` is just a string and does *not* accept HTML, If the button is a `<button>` tag you could use `html()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
   init: function() {
       this.form = $('#billing-form');
       this.submitButton = this.form.find('input[type=submit]');
       this.submitButtonValue = this.submitButton.val();

       var stripeKey = $('meta[name="publishable-key"]').attr('content');
       Stripe.setPublishableKey(stripeKey);

       this.bindEvents();
    },

    bindEvents: function() {
        this.form.on('submit', $.proxy(this.sendToken, this));
    },

    sendToken: function(event) {
        this.submitButton.val('<input type="image" src="http://localhost:8000/loader.gif">').prop('disabled', true);

        Stripe.createToken(this.form, $.proxy(this.stripeResponseHandler, this));

        event.preventDefault();
    },
```

Html is just a standard button like so:

```
     <input type="submit" value="Subscribe">
```

Comment: Is this your markup? If so you should add it to the question, not an answer ?

Comment: It was too long to put in a answer

Comment: Sorted it I had this.submitButton = this.form.find('input[type=submit]');

INstead of this.submitButton = this.form.find('button[type=submit]');

Answer (score 0):

this might be a solution to your problem:

```
<button type="submit">Button</button>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').on('click', function(){
       $(this).append('<img src="" width="10" height="10" />'); 
    });
});
```

notice that I have used button in my example, not input, as inputs do not allow to apply any content inside

if you want to stick to the input markup, consider adding it some class when loading, eg.

```
.loading {
    background: url(...)
}
```

here is a jsfiddle to first example:
http://jsfiddle.net/Xu84a/

Comment: basically wanting to show something like a spinning gif to the button once its clicked an awaiting response from ajax from Stripe servers

Comment: both solutions do that